# How to clone a project from Github and save it as a Workspace in VS Code via terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal, visual-studio-code, console

Every time I start a new project I create a repo on GitHub, clone it, open it in VS Code and save it as a Workspace before start to work on it. Is there a way to speed up this process via terminal, for example creating a function*?

(*)Mostly every project is in a specific "project-folder", so also it would be great to add the path to this folder in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, I created a function and pasted it in my alias.

First of all, I have an alias to go to my project folder, that I'll use in my function:

```
alias pf="/Users/username/Documents/Projects-Folder/"


gitme () {
  echo '\n\n Go to Projects folder';
  pf;
  echo '\n'

  echo 'Cloning '$@' repo from GitHub';
  git clone https://github.com/username/$@.git;
  echo '\n'

  echo 'Creating a workspace for VS Code';
  echo '{"folders":[{"path": "'$@'"}],"settings": {}}' > "$@".code-workspace
  echo '\n'

  echo 'Opening Project in VS Code';
  code "$@".code-workspace;
  echo '\n'
}
```

Now every time I create a new project I just type via terminal

```
gitme new-project
```

and that's it!

***Important***: the name of repo has to be the name to trigger the function and this will be the name of the workspace.